# Timeout transaction when processing long running job in javaee

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, jobs

Currently we have a job that imports n records from an import file to the database. The class is structured like this:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ImportJob implements Job {
    @Inject
    private ImportJobBean importJobBean;

    @Timeout
    public void trigger(Timer timer) {
        importJobBean.execute();
    }
}

@Stateless
public class ImportJobBean {
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void execute() {
        //call other Stateless beans here
    }
}
```

ImportJob is the entry point that calls ImportJobBean. There is no problem when I import 10K records but when I tried 100K, I encountered the error below.

```
12:07:21,986 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
12:07:21,987 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-4) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

Any advise on what's the best approach to execute this feature?

My tech stack:
-javaee7
-postgresql
-hibernate
jboss

Thanks,
czetsuya

Comment: At leat to bypass this  you can edit your standalone.xml and search for `<coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>`. Raise the 300 value for something you think will be closer to the time you need to process it.

Comment: Hi @alphamikevictor. Thanks for the info but what I'm imagining is something like start the job without transaction, and only activate transaction in the part where data is needed to be flush in the database. I'm trying transactionAttribute.not_supported and will get back with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we had for this issue is to annotation the main job runner with Tx.NEVER and then divide and conquer the records (or map-reduce) for example by entity ids. And finally create another SSB with method annotated with Tx.REQUIRES_NEW.

So it's basically like:

```
SSB (Job Runner), TX.NEVER
-SSB (Job Bean), TX.NEVER
--SSB (Async Bean), @Asynchronous, TX.NEVER
---SSB (Unit Bean), TX.REQUIRES_NEW
```

However, this also means that we cannot fail the Job altogether so we save the error on the unit level for re-execution.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the new [Batch API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html).

Comment: Unfortunately we already have a framework using JavaEE6 Timer.